# I am using ES6 import export on Node.js and getting module not found error

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, import, export

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mail-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  }
```

**server.js**

```
import express from "express";
import router from "./appRoutes/index.js";
```

**appRoutes/index.js**

```
import express from "express";
import { createChannel, getMessages } from "../controllers/channel";

export const router = express.Router();
```

**Folder Structure**

```
+--appRoutes
+-----index.js
|
|
+--Server.js
```

Comment: Please post the whole error.

Answer (score 1):

If you export your router by export const, you need to import it with curly braces, as you do not export it as default

what you could try is in your *server.js*:

> import {router} from "./appRoutes/index.js";

or another approach would be

#### appRoutes/index.js

```
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();

// your routes

export default routes;
```

Then in your

#### server.js

```
import whatEverNameYouWant from "./appRoutes/index.js";
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_a_single_export_from_a_module